# Why ajax success is called once?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, jquery

Why, if i write html method in javascript, it's called only once, but if i have only alert, it's calles every time, i change wy value in input (blur).

```
$(".quantity").blur(function() {
    console.log("upd");
    $.ajax({ 
      url: "/line_items/update_quantity/"+$(this).attr("id"), 
      type: "GET", 
      data: {quantity: $(this).val()},
      success: function(text)
      {
        alert(text);
        $('.right').html(text);
      },
      error: function(){
        alert('Ошибка javascript');
      },
      dataType : "html"
    });
  });
```

I need reload html partial after every blur...

Comment: do you try `$('.right').empty().html(text);`

Comment: @The System Restart  yes, no effect

Comment: is `.quantity` dynamic element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try doing this..

```
$(document).on('blur', '.quantity', function() {
   // place your code here
});
```

I suspect you're replacing the dom element that the original blur binding is applied against.  If you do that you remove the event handler.  [On()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) will keep it alive.

Comment: FYI: on() is the replacement for delegate() and live() as of jQuery 1.7

Answer (score 1):

If `.quantity` is dynamic element (I think so) then try

```
$(document).delegate('.quantity', 'blur', function() {
   // code
});
```

[read here about delegate()](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/)

Comment: From the documentation: "As of jQuery 1.7, .delegate() has been superseded by the .on() method.".